# underlying datatable doesn't get the row from datagridview

Tags: c#, vb.net, datagridview

Now, this one can be very obvious for someone, but I am stuck right on this:

Datagridview is bound to a binding source and the binding source is bound to a datatable.

Datagridview is now showing an empty row (with an asterisk).

[image]

When I click on a cell a cursor icon appears near that asterisk.

[image]

Now I am entering data in that row. When I enter a value in the first cell, a new row appears underneath this one, and the asterisk icon moves to that row. CellValueChanged gets fired, BUT in the watch window, the datatable still doesn't have that row.

[image]

[image]

I am finishing all columns and hitting a save button, BUT still in the watch window is see that the underlying datatable is not holding that row.

[image]

How to get that change back to datatable? Do I need to call some method after clicking that save button? I've tried with _detailDataTable.AcceptChanges(); but nothing happened.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Call `EndEdit` on the `BindingSource`. DEFINITELY do not call `AcceptChanges`! That doesn't get called until you have actually saved the changes. It will be invoked implicitly when you call `Update` on your adapter. If you call it first then there will be no changes to save.

Comment: As I said to you that was just so easy, but for me, that was not, even though I was using EndEdit but in the wrong place. Now I know the importance of EndEdit, thanks!